# Linux Backup.... include empty swapfile

Tags: linux, backup, raspberry-pi, tar

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR

tar -cvJf backup.tar.xz --exclude=/backup.tar.xz --one-file-system /

I can add Exclude --exclude=/var/cache/swap/swap1...(**not excluding the file segfaults the process** *and or can crash the lil bast@#$*)
as this is  [RPI3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/) , with some custom built packages...  anyhow it would be nice to run this as a docker/rkt , for faster compile times...

I however would prefer to back up this file as a **place-holder** (ie 0 bytes or just an empty file...) **for compatibility reasons I need the empty file**...
*(it will be replaced on boot with swap data... on boot)* , 
however not sure if on restore it/**system would flake** out.?? , 
so hence i'm trying to add it back via script into the archive.

I'm just not sure how to get tar to add the 1 file as empty...  or append archive as 1 empty file @ path...

***How to append the empty file in my backup script would be a a plus*** , more elegant...

, however i can force it via docker/restore script. via touch /var/cache/swap/swap1 , or by stuffing it unmoundted (from RPI3)  in my laptop or Sabayon-virtualbox etc... 
browse and stuff it back in...  also a pain in the @####...

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# backup Gentoo RPi3 64 Necrose99 
#
#  if portage has lots of packages it will bloat the backup. , Swapfile will crash the backup.
# can use the script to dump fs also for docker. 
tar -cvJf /backup.tar.xz --exclude=/var/cache/swap/swap1 --exclude=/usr/portage/*  --exclude=/backup.tar.xz --one-file-system /

## TO DO , find a way to tuck the swap1 file back.. into archive...
```

Comment: mainly as general backup/restore, and i can also use the tarball as a docker/qemu  , for far faster compiles .. at GNU tar can'nt be told to --empty-file/var/cache/swap/swap1 , wich would give me an place holder for the swap... which would be ideal...